# Wrong XSLT code?

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, xslt-1.0

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Groups>
    <GroupData ID="xxx" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="zzz" Value="3"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="yyy" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="abc" Value="3"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="zzz" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="pqr" Value="1982"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="xxx" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="www" Value="1982"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="yyy" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="def" Value="1982"/>
    </GroupData>
    <GroupData ID="zzz" Temp="yyy">
        <ItemData ID="tuv" Value="1982"/>
    </GroupData>
</Groups>
```

That I would like to be transformed into smth like this:

```
<GroupData ID="xxx" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
 <ItemData ID="zzz" Value="3"/>
 <ItemData ID="www" Value="1982"/>
</GroupData>
```

and so on with the other `GroupData` ids.

And this is my non-working XSLT code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="ItemData"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Groups/GroupData[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-data', ItemData)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('group-data', ItemData)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

P.S. I have been looking at the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) and one other thread from this forum, but I wanted to write it by myself, because I will have to apply it on a bigger and more twisted XML document.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that is wrong is your key

```
<xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="ItemData"/>
```

This indicates you want to group **GroupData** elements by the contents of the child **ItemData** element. But all you **ItemData** elements have no value, so you will just have one 'group'. It looks like you actually want to group by the **ID** attribute here

```
<xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="@ID"/>
```

Now, in your **xsl:for-each** you have the correct syntax for getting the distinct group elements, but within the loop you only really want to create a copy of this first distinct **GroupData** and then copy the child **ItemData** elements of all the items in the group.

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*|key('group-data', @ID)/ItemData"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="@ID"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="Groups/GroupData[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-data', @ID)[1])]">
         <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:copy-of select="@*|key('group-data', @ID)/ItemData"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually, it would could be better here if you were to make use of the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy elements, and use templates, which are more in the spirit of XSLT. Try this instead:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="group-data" match="GroupData" use="@ID"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Groups/GroupData[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-data', @ID)[1])]" />
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="GroupData">
       <GroupData>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|key('group-data', @ID)/ItemData" />
       </GroupData>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tested my code at http://xslttest.appspot.com/ and it looks fine to me.....

Comment: Nah, my mistake, it's ok. 
But I am getting it like 

`<GroupData ID="xxx" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
<ItemData ID="zzz" Value="3">
</ItemData>
<ItemData ID="www" Value="1982">
</ItemData>
</GroupData>`

And I would like it to be 

`<GroupData ID="xxx" Key="4" Temp="yyy">
<ItemData ID="zzz" Value="3" />
<ItemData ID="www" Value="1982" />
</GroupData>`

In short: the `<ItemData to be closed like this />` but not with separate tag.

Comment: I've added the xsl output statement which might make a difference

Comment: Can you just clarify what's the purpose of `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>` 

and the templates at all.

Comment: This is the XSLT identity transform, which is quite a fundamental design pattern in XSLT, and is used to copy existing nodes but given you the flexibilty to override it. Google "xslt identity transform" for more information.